# FParsec - how to parse strings separated by pipes?

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm using a FParsec to write a small org-mode parser, for fun, and I'm having a little trouble with parsing a table row into a list of strings. My current code looks like this:

```
let parseRowEntries :Parser<RowEntries, unit> =
    let skipInitialPipe = skipChar '|'
    let notaPipe  = function
        | '|' -> false
        | _ -> true
    let pipeSep = pchar '|'

    skipInitialPipe >>. sepEndBy (many1Satisfy notaPipe) pipeSep
    |>> RowEntries
```

This works fine until you parse the string `|blah\n|blah\n|blah|` which should fail because of the newline character. Unfortunately simply making `\n` false in the `notaPipe` condition causes the parser to stop after the first 'blah' and say it was parsed successfully. What I want the manySatisfy to do is parse (almost) any characters, stopping at the pipe, failing to parse for newlines (and likely the eof character).

I've tried using `charsTillString` but that also just halts parsing at the first pipe, without an error.

Comment: So the rule is that a line must start *and* end with a pipe character, right? I.e., `|foo|\n|bar|\n` is valid, but `|foo\n|bar\n` is invalid because there's no terminating pipe? In that case I think what you want is something using the `between` combinator. I'll do a few tests and then write up an answer with what I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your spec correctly, this should work:

```
let parseOneRow :Parser<_, unit> =
    let notaPipe  = function
        | '|' -> false
        | '\n' -> false
        | _ -> true
    let pipe = pchar '|'

    pipe >>. manyTill (many1Satisfy notaPipe .>> pipe) (skipNewline <|> eof)

let parseRowEntries :Parser<_, unit> =
    many parseOneRow

run parseRowEntries "|row|with|four|columns|\n|second|row|"
// Success: [["row"; "with"; "four"; "columns"]; ["second"; "row"]]
```

The structure is that each row starts with a pipe, then the segments within a row are conceptually `row|`, `with|`, and so on. The `.>>` combinator discards the pipe. The reason the "till" part of that line uses `skipNewline` instead of `newline` is because the `eof` parser returns `unit`, so we need a parser that expects newlines and returns `unit`. That's the `skipNewline` parser.

I've tried throwing newlines in where they don't belong (before the pipes, for example) and that causes this parser to fail exactly as it should. It also fails if a column is empty (that is, two pipe characters occur side by side like `||`), which I think is also what you want. If you want to allow empty rows, just use `manySatisfy` instead of `many1Satisfy`.

Comment: P.S. I tried the `between` combinator, but the fact that the separator is the same as the end character made the `between` parser a bit tricky to use. It's possible that it could have worked, but I ended up taking a different approach rather than figure out how to make `between` work.

Comment: I also tried to use the between parser, but went in circles with it. The `|` at the beginning and end threw i for a loop.

Comment: Minor change I made was to turn many1Satisfy into manySatisfy (because technically `||` is a valid entry.